# Optimize calculating distance between two borders

Tags: algorithm, bitmap, distance

I have a bitmap world map where each country is drawn in a unique color. Upon loading the map I have stored all border pixels in an array per country.

Next I calculate the distance between two counties (A and B). I do this by looping over every pixel in A's border array and calculating the distance between it and every pixel in B's border array. After finding the shortest distance I store it in a lookup table.

To optimize this I have:

- Filtered out all immediate neighbors beforehand
- When trying to find the shortest distance between two pixels I only compare the squared distance (only when I've found the closest one do I calculate the actual distance using square root).
- When storing the distance I store it for both A->B and B->A so B will then only calculate distance against C to Z and C only against D to Z, etc.

With a large map this still takes quite a lot of time, so are there any other optimizations that I could do?

Comment: Are there no other ideas or suggestions? I find it hard to believe that I haven't missed any other optimizations that could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the border pixel data in quadtree or another hierarchical structure exploiting the actual geometry (perhaps in a triangular tree). Instead of calculating true distances for N*N/2 pixels, you will calculate ranges of min/max distances for log2(N)*log2(N)/2 areas containing the border pixels, ruling out large sets of impossible candidates, then refining to next level.

[image]

Here in sample A, there are 12 squares to be compared to 4 candidate squares of sample B, leading probably to 4*5 next level candidates (all B squares and 5 closest regions in A).

Comment: Using a grid to limit the number of comparisons was my initial approach as well, but I was never able to figure out a fool-proof way of implementing it. First of all you have the obvious problem of two pixels being closer to each other than another set of pixels despite their grid boxes being further apart. What also complicates it is that many countries have complex shapes or are shattered across a large area in forms of islands etc.

Comment: The approach is conservative -- it gives false positives. This is exemplified by the statement, that there are four candidate blocks of level 1 for B. This is exactly because min(B,SouthEast) = max(B, NorthWest); Only after going to a deeper level the search can outrule all subregions of B_SE. The algorithm doesn't ever converge to a single subregion -- but when the size of the subregion is a single pixel, there are just a handful of candidates A*B to perform the brute force search.

Comment: The distance of two grid boxes is always a range: from 0 to thousands. But when dist(A0,B0) = [123, 400] and dist(A71,B13) = [500,503] one can discard areas A71,B13 and concentrate on A0,B0.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But to get the correct distance I would have to iterate all the way down to where a grid box is just one pixel, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Also you can use bounding circles + radii as the distance estimator -- in the end r_a = r_b = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Consider calculating distance not between every pixel border of A and B but let's say each 10-th. This will give you rough solution. If the precision is not enough for your purpose, you can make it more accurate by more comparisons.

Another approach may be to introduce new model of border data structure. Store it not as each point but the set of 'characteristic' points

Comment: Precision is important though, so your first suggestion does not work. I'm not sure I understand the second suggestion - but it sounds like it would run into the precision demand as well.